# R: How to apply a similar mutate() to multiple data frames with purrr without creating a list?

Tags: r, purrr

I have seen similar posts, but none that address this question specifically.
So, I have three data frames that are similar, and I'm applying a similar `mutate()` to each of them.

```
xk <- xk %>% 
    mutate(country="Kosovo",
           date=ym(date)) %>% 
    relocate(country)

al <- al %>% 
    mutate(country="Albania",
           date=ym(date)) %>% 
    relocate(country)

mne <- mne %>% 
    mutate(country="Montenegro",
           date=my(date)) %>% 
    relocate(country)
```

Can I use one of the functions contained in the `purrr` package to do that with as few lines of code as possible?

Comment: `purrr` functions are used in lists.  So, not clear about your question.  I would suggest to create a function that takes the country value, and the format for 'date' and reuse

Comment: You can't use `purrr` to apply the same function to multiple dataframe outside a list. You have to create a list first.

Comment: Perhaps try with `pmap` i.e. `pmap(list(list(xk, al, mne), c("Kosovo", "Albania", "Montenegro"), list(ym, ym, my)), ~ ..1 %>% mutate(country = ..2, date = (..3)(date)))`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

there is a way that will work with or without purrr.

1. convert your data.frames to data.tables
2. use mapply (or the purrr's equivalent) to do the same operation on all tables
3. you don't care about the output of mapply, because data.tables will be changed without assignment to a new variable

```r
library(data.table)
xk <- as.data.table(xk)
al <- as.data.table(al)
mne <- as.data.table(mne)

mapply(function(x,y) x[,country:=y], x=list(xk,al,mne), y=c("Kosovo","Albania","Montenegro"))

print(xk)
```

Comment: Since. I'd like to have the data frames separately (not in a list), is there a better way with a for loop for that?

Comment: they will not be in a list. the data.tables xk, al and mne will remain separate tables, but changed the way you want them to be